# Writing mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've table:

```
name position rating try_count
Bob    87       15      20
Erick 115       46      28
John   95       32      17
Karl  208       25       5
```

We need to write a stored procedure that computes the name of the most efficient player. The efficiency is calculated using the formula (position / try_count) * rating. The higher the number obtained, the more effective the player was. Prerequisite: the calculation must be performed using a loop(while) and a temporary table. I don't know how to do it, Google can't help me too :(

Thanks all!

Comment: Did you try anything before asking? What problems did you have? SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: The prerequisites are odd - I doubt any sql coder would tackle the problem with this approach can you elaborate please and is there any other tech involved.

Comment: I have such conditions that need to be clarified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that conforms to your stated requirement.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P;
CREATE TABLE T
(name VARCHAR(10),position INT,rating INT,try_count INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES
('Bob'   , 87     ,  15   ,   20),
('Erick' ,115     ,  46   ,   28),
('John'  , 95     ,  32   ,   17),
('Karl'  ,208     ,  25   ,    5);

delimiter $$
create procedure p()
begin
    declare i int;
    set i = 1;
    drop temporary table if exists temp;
    create temporary table temp as 
        select *,
                 (position / try_count) * rating as performance
        from t;
        while I = 1 do
            select * from temp order by performance desc limit 1;
            set i = 2;
        end while;
end  $$

delimiter ;

call p();

+------+----------+--------+-----------+-------------+
| name | position | rating | try_count | performance |
+------+----------+--------+-----------+-------------+
| Karl |      208 |     25 |         5 |   1040.0000 |
+------+----------+--------+-----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.048 sec)
```

It's nonsense of course..